# Access VBA & SQL date formats

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I'm having problems with date format in an SQL statement

```
CurrentTime = Format(CurrentTime, "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm")
SQL = "SELECT Count([ID]) AS Booked FROM [Appointment Slots] WHERE [Appointment Slots].Time=#" & CurrentTime & "#"
```

The bizarre thing here is that sometimes when I run the code this works.  Other times, and without changing the code, it doesn't, but then it works when I change the date format to mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm then it works for a while then stops working until I change it back to dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm

Clearly something is going wrong with the regional date settings and how it's storing dates but I can't pin down a solution to this.  Is there no way to compare a date in Access SQL that is independent of format?

Comment: A parameter query is a neat way to avoid date format issues, and also avoid needing to include `#` delimiters for date literals.  If the query expects a date parameter, you just give it a date value.

Comment: This worked best of the solutions I tried, can you write it as an answer so I can mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there no way to compare a date in Access SQL that is independent of
>   format?

Consider a query with a parameter in its `WHERE` clause, similar to this ...

```sql
WHERE [Appointment Slots].Time=[Enter Appointment Time]
```

You can also add a `PARAMETERS` clause at the beginning of your SQL statement, but it's not absolutely required ...

```sql
PARAMETERS [Enter Appointment Time] DateTime;
```

So when the query expects a Date/Time parameter, you just give it a Date/Time value.

A parameter query avoids date format issues, and also avoids the need for `#` date delimiters in the SQL statement.

Answer (score 4):

You should make it a habit using the *ISO sequence*, and *nn* for minutes.

Also escape the "/" and ":" to have a true slash and colon, otherwise they will be replaced with the localized date and time separators:

```
CurrentTime = Format(CurrentTime, "yyyy\/mm\/dd hh\:nn")
```

This also works for *ADO* and *FindFirst*, which the "reverse" US format (mm/dd/yyyy) does not.

Comment: *"otherwise they will be replaced with the localized date and time separators"*  Thanks for that.  Would "yyyy-mm-dd" format also be subject to that localization substitution?

Comment: No, and indeed not for dates where / and : are the only separator characters. Elsewhere, you also have the dot as the separator for milliseconds, but that is not handled natively by Access and VBA.

Comment: Thanks again.  I'd seen `"yyyy\/mm\/dd"` used before, but never understood why it was useful.  Since I'm in U.S., I'm too ignorant about many localization details. ;-)

Comment: I think it is in France they use a space as a separator. That can really cause strange happenings in SQL.

Comment: Thanks, this still didn't work however.  Resetting my regional settings to US formats and then re-entering data in US format and the code worked.  Also - the suggestion from HansUp in a comment on the OP of using parameter queries also seemed to work.

Answer (score 1):

Date format `#....#`, used in queries works correctly only with american date format mm/dd/yyyy

The best way for working with dates is passing them as parameters to query. In this case used internal format, which doesn't depend on regional settings.

Comment: It also works with the ISO sequence. And using a slash only _will_ cause the expression to be localized.