# Inserting dates in Access using VBA

Tags: sql, vba, date, ms-access, format

I have a date field in my table, with "dd/mm/yyyy" format.

I am trying to insert into that field a variable through a form using VBA code. I have this:

```
vardtedate = CDate(Format(Me.dtedate.Value, "dd/mm/yyyy"))
DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO table (dtedate) VALUES (#" & vardtedate & "#);"
```

It works fine, but only when the day is over 12.
If I try to insert something like '12/06/2016' it shows it reversed, like '06/12/2016', and the field takes that date as 6th of december instead of 12 of june. What am I doing wrong? What am I missing?

I tried to parametize and the problem persists.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access VBA & SQL date formats](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35917305/access-vba-sql-date-formats) . Don't mind that this question is about a SELECT statement, the problem is identical.

Comment: Parameterize the query and use `Date` types instead of `String`s.

Comment: Not sure if that works `vardtedate = CDate(Format(Me.dtedate.Value, "mm/dd/yyyy"))`. Reverse month and day when you set vardtedate

Comment: @Andre I tried to parametize following the answers in there and I'm still having the same issue.

Comment: @Comintern still having the same issue

Comment: Please edit your question and add the new code with parameter.

Comment: @Andre I found the solution! I'll edit my post in a few minutes with the answer. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 2):

So I was looking for solutions and I found this thread [Inserting current DateTime into Audit table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11084663/inserting-current-datetime-into-audit-table). Apparently when you try to insert a date value through a sql statement it converts ambiguous date formats to "mm/dd/yyyy". I formatted the variable to "yyyy/mm/dd" and now works perfectly.

```
vardtedate = CDate(Format(Me.dtedate.Value, "dd/mm/yyyy"))
DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO table (dtedate) VALUES (#" & Format(vardtedate, "yyyy-mm-dd") & "#);"
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it has to do with the regional settings your desktop is set to.  United States data conventions, are totally different from European, or some other standard.  See the link below for details.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Set-default-values-for-fields-or-controls-99508d03-b28b-4057-9652-dac1c4c60d86

As you found out, setting the format forces a fix.

Answer (score 0):

CDate(Format(Date.Now, "MM/dd/yyyy"))